# Add condition of user capability in WP_query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, capabilities

I am struggling a bit with my WP_query which includes a meta_query to limit posts based on ACF User field, but show all posts if user can 'edit_posts'. From my code below, the first two arrays work fine where;

1. Current user ID is selected in the ACF field; or
2. The ACF user field is empty and thus a value of ''; or
3. The current user capability is 'edit_posts'.

If any of the 3 conditions are present, the posts show accordingly. It's the third condition which is not working and need some help with. This is my code so far:

```
    $user_exception = current_user_can('edit_posts');
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'promotions',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'meta_key'          => 'promo_start_date',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query'     => array(
            'relation'      => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'dedicated_promotion',
                'value'   => $current_user_id,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'dedicated_promotion',
                'value'   => '',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'wp_capabilities', //This part is current not working as I intended 
                'value' => $user_exception,
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    ) );
?>
```

Anyone have some pointers into how to retrieve current logged in user capabilities and add this to the meta_query?

Answer (score 1):

#**SOLVED**#
Issue is solved by defining the meta_query conditions with an if statement. So if current_user_can('subscriber') the meta_query includes the conditions, otherwise the query includes all posts.

This is the code in case this is helpful for anyone else:

```
<?php
//create variables
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
//check if current user is a subscriber and define meta_query arguments

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'promotions',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_key'          => 'promo_start_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged
);

if (current_user_can( 'subscriber' )) {
    // Add meta_query
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'dedicated_promotion',
            'value'   => $current_user_id,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'dedicated_promotion',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '='
        )
      );
}

//set up the query
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
```